# Iterate though a Object and echo values

Tags: php, object, loops, foreach

I tried a lot of different methods. I managed to get the first part working but the second part to get the fruits name isn't working.

I have an object stored in `$food`, the `print_r()` output of this object is shown below:

```
Food Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [values] => Array
        (
            [name] => Myfood
        )
    [objects] => Array
        (
            [0] => Fruits Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => My Fruits
                        )
                    [objects] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => FruitType Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [values] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => Orange1
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

This code displays 'Myfood' successfully:

```
foreach ($food->values as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value";
}
```

This code displays 'My fruits' successfully:

```
echo '<br/>';
            
foreach ($food->objects as $id => $owner) {
    foreach ($owner->values as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key => $value";
    }
}
```

I need a second block of code that displays the `FruitType` object values `Orange1`, I tried a few things but didn't work out well.

Comment: If you're just doing this for debugging sake, look at var_dump().

Comment: @ScoPi `var_dump() == print_r()` I think it's safe to say it's a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you've run into the greatest stumbling block all developers face... naming things.  I've probably not done too much better as I'm not 100% sure what your end goal is but you were on the right track as far as nesting loops is concerned.

```
foreach ($food->objects as $i => $obj) {
    echo "name => {$obj->values['name']}\n";
    foreach ($obj->objects as $j => $type) {
        foreach($type->values as $key => $val){
            echo "    $key => $val\n";
        }
    }
}
```

[Working Example](http://codepad.org/io2c0nyC)

Looking at the structure of your object though - recursive iteration may be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the `get_object_vars()` function ?

see more here : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.get-object-vars.php

Comment: var_dump is what produced the object chunk above. I`m sure there`s another loop that can be added to pull the 'fruitstype' fromt his code. I just cant figure it out -_-  [code]                                             foreach ($food->objects as $id => $owner) {
    foreach ($owner->values as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key => $value";
    }
}[/code]